# 'ConfigureServices returning a System.IServiceProvider isn't supported.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, asp.net-core-3.0

I need ti use this `AutoFac` in ASP core 3.0

When I use this code in startu up:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    return services.BuildAutofacServiceProvider();
}
```

It show me this error:

> 'ConfigureServices returning an System.IServiceProvider isn't supported.'

And I change the program.cs by this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

But it not solved.

This is `BuildAutofacServiceProvider()` Code:

```
public static IServiceProvider BuildAutofacServiceProvider(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var ContainerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    ContainerBuilder.Populate(services);
    ContainerBuilder.AddService();
    var container = ContainerBuilder.Build();

    return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Startup syntax has changed for configuring Autofac for ASP.NET Core 3.0+

In addition to using the following on the host builder

```
.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
```

In `Startup` do the following format

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    //... normal registration here

    // Add services to the collection. Don't build or return
    // any IServiceProvider or the ConfigureContainer method
    // won't get called.

    services.AddControllers();
}

// ConfigureContainer is where you can register things directly
// with Autofac. This runs after ConfigureServices so the things
// here will override registrations made in ConfigureServices.
// Don't build the container; that gets done for you. If you
// need a reference to the container, you need to use the
// "Without ConfigureContainer" mechanism shown later.
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder) {
    // Register your own things directly with Autofac
    builder.AddMyCustomService();

    //...
}
```

Reference [Autofac documentation](https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting) for ASP.NET Core 3.0+

Comment: It's somewhat important to note that this isn't an Autofac-specific change. ASP.NET Core 3.0 stopped supporting returning an `IServiceProvider` when they switched to use the generic application host. Using a service provider factory is now the only way to integrate any third-party DI container.

Comment: @TravisIllig Thanks for pointing this out! But I've got one question: is builder.Populate(services) still workable and needed?

Comment: No. It'd be good if you read the documentation linked in the answer here, it has a total walkthrough with examples.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `Host` in Program.cs you can use `WebHost`

```
public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
  }

  public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

In this case following code works

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...
  var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

  builder.Populate(services);
  var container = builder.Build();
  return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must change program.c

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
   WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .ConfigureLogging(options => options.ClearProviders())
       .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of Host use WebHost in Program.cs

It work for me ...

Comment: This looks more like a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63701478/2227743) rather than a new answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31052559)